# I try to find the reverse number of the input number in java program .Yeah but i am confused about the logic inside the loop

Tags: java, for-loop

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int n;
    System.out.print("Enter a number :");
    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
    n=sc.nextInt();
    int reversednum=0;
    while(n!=0){
        int remainder=n%10;
        reversednum=reversednum*10+remainder;
        n=n/10;
    }
    System.out.println(reversednum);
}
```

for input n = 123, reversednum = 0 * 10 + 3 = 3 again then n = 12 ,reversednum = 0 * 10 + 2, reversednum = 0 * 10 + 1 is this the logic run inside while loop? Or reversednum = 0 * 10 + 3 = 3, n = 12 reversednum = 3 * 10 + 2; n = 1 reversednum= 32 * 10 + 1; if the second concept is true then it prints 32321 if we print  reversednum inside the while loop.

Comment: Please checkout [editing help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) and [ask]

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need every last element of that number so for that logic is below.

```
public class reverseNumber {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

         System.out.print("Enter a number :");
         Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
         int number = sc.nextInt();

         int reverse = 0;

        while (number != 0) {
            int remainder = number % 10;
            reverse = reverse * 10 + remainder;
            number = number / 10;
        }

        System.out.println("The reverse of the given number is: " + reverse);
    }
}
```

> ## **Logic Explanation**

**1**. Loop runs until `reverse` variable will not 0.

```
while(number != 0)
```

**2**. This gives last number of that variable for Example. If we have 12345 then after this code line runs it gives 5 because when you do the number modulo 10 then it gives last one number.

```
int remainder = number % 10;
```

**3.** In this reverse variable we can store that last number.

```
reverse = reverse * 10 + remainder;
```

The value of the reverse is 0 at the start then remainder of first time is 5 so the value of the reverse is `(reverse = 0 + 10 + 5)` then at first time value of reverse is 5.

**4.** after that the original number is divided by 10 and remove last index of that number. for example 12345 then it removes 5 for that number and go on until the number is not 0.

```
number = number / 10;
```

Comment: Thankyou , then n=1234, reverse =5*10+4=54 ;at n=123, reverse=54*10+3=543.....thanks

Comment: consider to upvoting the answer if answer is satisfied. Happy to help.